# Mutual information and additivity under independence?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

So I've been trying to figure this out since I saw it quoted in  a paper. Suppose $y$ and $z$ are two independent variables. Is it true then that $I(x;y) + I(x;z) \leq I(x:y,z)$? My intuition is that since $y $ and $z$ are independent, the information gain from taking them singly (in sequence) or together is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is straightforward from computation.
$$\begin{align}&I(x;y)+I(x;z)-I(x;y,z)\\
=&H(y)-H(y|x)+H(z)-H(z|x)-(H(y,z)-H(y,z|x))\\
=&H(y)+H(z)-H(y,z)+H(y,z|x)-H(y|x)-H(z|x)\\
=&I(y;z)-I(y;z|x)\\
\leq&0\end{align}$$
The last inequality comes from the independence of $y$ and $z$ which results $I(y;z)=0$. Intuitively thinking, though $y$ and $z$ are independent, if $x$ is a function of $y,z$, we may indeed obtain connections between them. For example, suppose $x,y,z$ are binary random variables and $x=y+z$ and given $x=1$, we can find connection between $y,z$, that is $y=1+z$.

Comment: You and the OP are both familiar with notations like $I(x;y)$, $H(y\mid x)$ etc. I am not. Can you give me a (very) short college on this in the form of a comment? I am familiar with probabilities.

Comment: @drhab: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Comment: @StefanHansen Clicking on the link in your comment sends me to this page (try it yourself). So I think something is wrong with it.

Comment: @drhab: Oops, edited the link.

Comment: @StefanHansen Gratias tibi ago. ('Thanks' is forbidden here)

Comment: @drhab Let me explain these notions in an intuitive way. These notions all go around a core concept called information. This is quite important. For example, he entropy $H(x)$ measures the uncertainty of random variable $X$. That means $X$ contains $H(X)$ that much information. And conditional entropy $H(X|Y)$ contains information of $X$ if we have already known $Y$. Then of course the information has been reduced. Similarly, $I(X;Y)$ measure those information that we can obtain from both $X$ and $Y$. This [diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) shows perfect what I said.

Comment: Again 'gratias tibi ago'. Somehow this is my introduction into information theory, and off course it will need its time to land in my brains. But I am not too old to learn.

Comment: Hi Shuchang. I followed your proof, upto the last step. But I am fuzzy on why $I(y;z)  \geq I(y;z|x)$? I suppose one can make an intuitive argument that one gains more information if one doesn't condition on $x$ , but it feels a bit opaque?

Comment: @Amir Sorry, it shall be $I(y;z|x)\geq0=I(y;z)$ and I add some additions.